# NSScrollView Elasticity

Tags: macos, nsscrollview

I had created a basic `UIRefreshControl` imitation in Mac apps using `NSScrollView` elasticity. This works fine in MacBooks and in an iMac but not in Mac Mini. It doesnt seem to have the elasticity in Scroll View. Is it a system setting or is this animation works only on MacBooks and iMacs ?

Comment: Are all Macs running the same OS version?

Comment: Found out its related to Apple Input devices.